# django-allauth email template styling

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth in my django application and the challenge I am facing has to do with the styling of the email sent. When a user registers, a confirmation mail is sent to the person but the email is just rendered as plain text. how can one style the email template.

Answer (score 1):

Styling can be done in the templates. Look in allauth/account/email_confirm.html and other template files in that location.

You will need to copy those files to your own template directory before editing.

Other email templates are there as well. Also look into the email subdirectory, which contains .txt files which are included by the templates.

Comment: I know about that. When I added the css classed the css does not reflect in the gmail

Comment: Did you add the css file in those templates directly or include them somehow?

Comment: If you make a simple text change in that template, is that reflected in the resulting email? (just making sure no templates are fetched elsewhere)